# Blazor client-side - DLLs not cached

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, cache-control

I created a simple Blazor app using the WebAssembly approach in .NET 6.
However, every-time I visit the website, it takes several seconds to load. About 8.5MB of data and over 50 files, most of which are the .net dlls.

As far as I understand, these should be cached by browser so on next visit it will be fluent experience.

I am not very familiar with frontend, so I was hoping this will work by default.
Is there something I have to do to achieve this behaviour? My app is built upon the Blazor template project.

EDIT:
Actually, in Chrome, the DLLs are cached (code 304 instead of 200), but it still takes few seconds to get the trivial home page. What is causing this? Is there some unavoidable initialization?

Comment: Having the same issue.
Default blazor wasm app, deployed on linux/apache.
Every F5 reloads 3.1MB from the server.